# What is the reason to reference jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There is such jQuery package called `jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js`
Download link:
http://code.google.com/p/deroc/downloads/detail?name=jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js&can=2&q=

The Project Home tab saying `Anything`

Could some one explain the benefits/idea of that plugin?

For example this package used here http://www.ryantetek.com/demos/page_tab/

Why should i reference this one instead of original jquery-ui ones?

Is it **jquery-ui-*.custom.min.js** was called before lake that?

Where it is originality was came from?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: it is not a real plugin but a custom build of jQuery UI. The reason it's used is (probably) that the user, at that time, built a custom jQuery UI download and then kept it linked to the page.
Anyway, there is no real need to use it instead of a standard jQuery download. I think it's even a **drawback**, because the page "(...)/page_tab" uses an outdated version of jQuery (1.2.6, now we're at 1.5.1) and jQuery UI (1.5.2, now we're at 1.8.12).

At the jQuery UI site (http://jqueryui.com/download) you can customize your jQuery UI download, since you may not need **all** of the functionalities of jQuery UI but only a subset (e.g., you could need just the DatePicker widget): in that case you can save space, and the download is "custom"-ized or "personalized": in fact, the file you'll download will have a name like

```
jquery-ui-X.Y.Z.custom.zip
```

where X.Y.Z is the the version number. In it you'll find a `jquery-ui-X.Y.Z.custom.min.js` file into the `js/` directory.

I think the file you mention is a kind of "personalization" in that sense; besides, it's been "packed" to save even more space.

Looking at the page you mention, it looks like this "personalization" contains, at least, the tabs widget; besides, the page adds a visual effect to the tab switching.

You may take a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-fx 
for more info about this kind of tabs visual customization.

Please note that the js file you get  from jQuery UI site is not "packed" but "min"-ified, which means it is readable but has all whitespace stripped. A packed js, on the other hand, is a compressed javascript source which is no more "human"-readable.

Comment: i was there but if i untick  any checkboxes and than download the file i didn't get any **jquery-ui-personalized-*.packed.js** in archive. or now it is called **jquery-ui-*.custom.min.js**?

Comment: Any ideas what is the original source of **jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js** ? Google showing a lot of references to that but nowhere i can see what is the source of that, where and how it was created and from where to get/update the latest version of that.